# PHP call R, image created when executed in terminal, but not from Web UI

Tags: php, r, apache, terminal

I am trying to run a R script from PHP, and in R script, I will create test.jpg image, and in PHP, I will display this image on web.

The R is 2.11.1 and OS is Ubuntu 10.10.

The problem is: this .jpg is created successfully if I run from terminal, but no image created if I run from WebUI. I run the script from terminal and WebUI in the same directory. /opt/lampp/htdocs/name/.  (If somebody can tell me a good tool to debug this WebUI, it would be great. I put some echo in the .php file, I see the functions being called, but still do not know how to solve this bug).

The .jpg is created when I run from terminal:

```
php r_caller.php
```

In this r_caller.php, I have simple function as:

```
<?php php_call_r(){
$cmd = "echo 'argv <- \"r_command.r\"; source(argv)' | " .
     "/usr/bin/R --vanilla --slave";
$ret = system($cmd);
echo $ret;}
?>
```

and this php_call_r function is called in the same file as r_caller.php:

```
<?php
//some irrelavant codes above
php_call_r();
print("<img src=test.jpg>");
?}
```

and in the r_command.r script, I have simple commands as:

```
jpeg("test.jpg") 
plot(50, 50)
dev.off()
```

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I am not sure about your problem, but have you considered using [rApache](http://rapache.net/)?

Comment: what is the output for `echo $ret`? Most probably permission issue or path issue.

Comment: To: nico, thanks for the suggestion. I just need to display this image, and I was told that this is totally visible, so I am hoping to fix this.

Comment: To: Sarwar, How to get this $ret, I tried to echo $ret on the web page, no result shown. The permission issue was my guess as well. so I tried to run this script in terminal from the same directory(/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_site_name/), and the image was created. I executed as normal mode, not in su mode. BUT no image created If I execute from Web UI. Is there a way to tell whether this is permission issue or not?

Comment: What version of R is running on the server? Older versions of R needed an X11 graphics server in order to produce images via the device functions like jpeg(). People tend to not upgrade their server versions as often as their desktops...

Comment: To: Spacedman, I checked the R version is 2.11.1(2010-5-31), and the OS I am runing is Ubuntu 10.10. I am wondering why I can get the .jpg output when I run from the terminal(call R from PHP indeed created the .jpg in terminal), but not in WebUI. Any other ideas? or debug tools?, thanks

Comment: What exactly is "WebUI"? Try running R from your terminal without the DISPLAY set - do: "DISPLAY= R" (thats a space between = and R). If you can still make a jpg from the terminal then your R doesn't need an X11 server and that's one possibility eliminated (assuming the same version on your terminal and from the web - if you've got >1 R installed on the box then you might be running different R versions from each)

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify your platform and R version, but on unix the `jpeg()` device may require X11 to render the image (which you may have in your interactive session but not in apache). You may be better off using the `Cairo` package or other means that don't require X11 session (recent R allows you to use alternative types in the `jpeg` call which you can also try - see `?jpeg`).

(As a side note there is a PHP client to Rserve which makes web requests much faster - running R itself is pretty much the slowest way to use R from PHP. If you don't want to install any packages then you may want to use at least `Rscript`)

Edit: Now that you have added the R version - that's a really ancient one, you should seriously consider upgrading it. You can try installing Cairo with that old R version, but you may possibly need to go back there as well.

One more thing to consider, check you file privileges - make sure `www-data` has write-permissions wherever you will be creating the file (e.g., see `echo system("pwd");` for the current directory R will be run in).

Answer (score 0):

Check the Apache error logs to see if there are any errors. Try adding the following to the beginning of your PHP code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

This might be a copy/paste error, but your php_call_r function is not properly defined as a function. I suggest the following:

```
<?php function php_call_r() {
    $cmd = "echo 'argv <- \"r_command.r\"; source(argv)' | " .
    "/usr/bin/R --vanilla --slave";
    $ret = system($cmd);
    echo $ret;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing R from PHP for each request is a very bad idea -- PHP piping is usually not reliable and R's output is optimized for interactive work rather than transmitting results. Moreover R starts for ages, so you waste lots of time and CPU power.

The better idea is to use R worker daemon, created by either Rserve or triggr -- Rserve has [PHP client](http://code.google.com/p/rserve-php/), for triggr you need to cook one on your own, but it is trivial; it may look like this:

#### R part (r.R)

```
require(triggr);
serve(function(data_from_php){
 cat(sprintf("Called with: %s\n",data_from_php));

 #<<Picture creation code>>
 
 #Break connection notifying PHP that picture is done
 return(endConnection("Done\r\n"));
},9090);
  # ^- Port you want to use for internal communication
```

#### PHP part

```
<?php
$s=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
echo "Connecting...\n";
                               
if(socket_connect($s,"localhost",9090)){
 echo "Connected!\n"; //v double \r\n is crucial
 $d="some data for R\r\n\r\n";
 socket_write($s,$d,strlen($d));
 //This blocks until picture is done
 $r=socket_read($s,6);

 //Here we can emit the page featuring <img>
 echo "Response was $r\n";
}
?>
```

Now you just fire `r.R` in background or under some auto-resurrection daemon and you are done.